# Modify the AdMob's SDK?

Tags: iphone, sdk, admob

I have a simple question, I have add in my project the AdMob's SDK with all the header and the "libGoogleAdMobAds.a" and I want to know if it's possible to have access to this file to change some line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the GADBannerView in the code.

If you try to use an UIView on Interface Builder and choose GADBannerView as the class of the object, the class wont link and you get that error.